# AJAX form upload not grabbing file - AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not sure if I am grabbing the file from the form correctly in the following jQuery code which uses AJAX to upload a file.

```
function uploadFile() {

    console.log("uploading");

    var form = document.getElementById('fileForm');
    var fileSelect = document.getElementById('browseInput');

    console.log("check1");
    var file = fileSelect.files;

    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('FileInput', file, file.name);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'default/ParseExcel', true);

    xhr.send(formData);

    console.log("complete");

}
```

I get the error that `file` is undefined on line 39 (which is the `formData.append()` line in the code above.

I'm not sure if I am supposed to be grabbing the file form the `form` variable or from the `fileSelect` variable.

The full error:

`TypeError: Argument 2 of FormData.append does not implement interface Blob.`

HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"
               method="POST"
               id="fileForm"
               onsubmit="uploadFile()"
               style="display:inline-block;">

        <input id="browseInput" type="file" name="FileInput" style="display: none"/>

        <label for="upload-click-handler"></label>
        <input id="upload-click-handler"  type="text" readonly />

        <button id="submitFormButton" type="submit" style="display: none"></button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function uploadFile(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formElement = document.getElementById('fileForm');
  var formData = new FormData(formElement);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'pack.php', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="fileForm" onsubmit="uploadFile(event)">
  <input id="browseInput" type="file" name="FileInput" />
  <button id="submitFormButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Output** using `var_dump($_FILES);`

```
array (size=1)
  'FileInput' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '3400.JPG' (length=8)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'E:\wamp\tmp\php38E2.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 164319
```